# Flexbox Container Overlay Buttons

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

So I'm not that great at programming sorry, but I use stack overflow and other sources to add site functionality and learn a little more each time.  I'm using a Flexible Grid System to display my main content, specifically to re-arrange navigational buttons on the page.

This works great for me, but I've been using an ancient onMouseOver effect to display text when the user moves over an image button link and I'm not happy with the way it looks, and using flex creates issues with text legibility when the sizing gets small.

Ideally, I'd like to use a css overlay on my buttons so I can replace the image with text and format it to my liking.  I've tried MANY different overlay solutions, but they all seem to use grid layouts and I can't get them to work with my flex layout for some reason.

Either the images get cropped, or the text can't completely cover the image due to layering issues, or (If I use the grid layout) I lose the flexible resizing capabilities that I really like on the site.

I'm hoping that this is a really simple fix.  I'm assuming I need to add a container to my flex layout to place the content over the top of the image, but a hint to where to start would be really appreciated.

Here's a link to the buttons in the flex layout with no overlay:

https://megaauctions.net/megaflextest.htm

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>MEGA Main Flex Buttons</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test-code-buttons-no-action-compact.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>

<div class="buttoncontainer">
  <buttonhomea class="buttonhomea column grad-yellow">
 <a href=#><img src="http://www.megaauctions.net/images/btn-auctions.gif" /></a>
  </buttonhomea>
  <buttonhomeb class="buttonhomeb column grad-babyblue">
   <a href="#"><img src="http://www.megaauctions.net/images/btn-buying.gif" /></a>
  </buttonhomeb>
  <buttonhomec class="buttonhomec column grad-salmon">
   <a href="#"><img src="http://www.megaauctions.net/images/btn-selling.gif" /></a>
  </buttonhomec>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS...

```
.buttoncontainer { 
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  background: url('http://www.megaauctions.net/images/bkg-subs-deep.gif');
}
.column {
  --columns: 12; /* number of columns in the grid system */
  --width: var(--width-mobile, 0); /* width of the element */
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 9px 1px 2px 1px;
  flex-basis: calc(var(--width) / var(--columns) * 94%);
}

/****** VIEWPORTS START ******/ 
@media (min-width: 350px) {
    .column {
    --width-mobile: var(--width-mobile);
    --width: var(--width-mobile);
  }
  .buttonhomea img, .buttonhomeb img, .buttonhomec img {
      width:100%;
      max-width:157px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 512px) {
    .column {
    --width-tabletp: var(--width-tablet);
    --width: var(--width-tabletp);
  }
  .buttonhomea img, .buttonhomeb img, .buttonhomec img {
      width:100%;
      max-width:157px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 650px) {
  .column {
    --width-tablet: var(--width-mobile);
    --width: var(--width-tablet);
  }
  .buttonhomea img, .buttonhomeb img, .buttonhomec img {
      width:100%;
      max-width:300px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .column {
    --width-desktop: var(--width-tablet);
    --width: var(--width-desktop);
  }
  .buttonhomea img, .buttonhomeb img, .buttonhomec img {
      width:100%;
      max-width:315px;
}
}
/****** VIEWPORTS END ******/   

.buttonhomea, .buttonhomeb, .buttonhomec {
  --width-mobile: 12;
  --width-tabletp: 4;
  --width-tablet: 4;
  --width-desktop: 4;
  height: 100%;
} 

 .grad-yellow {
    background-color:#f3d250;
    background-image:linear-gradient(140deg,#f3d250,#EEA315);
}
.grad-babyblue {
    background-color:#90CCF4;
    background-image:linear-gradient(140deg,#90CCF4,#578FEE);
}
.grad-salmon {
    background-color:#F78888;
    background-image:linear-gradient(140deg,#F78888,#E7298C);
}
```

code in fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mattcomps/gfb7k43h/

...and an overlay example of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://megaauctions.net/megaflextestbuttonaction.htm

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>CSS Grid Cards</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test-code-buttons-working-grid-compact.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <section class="cards">

    <a href="#" class="card grad-yellow">
      <div class="card__overlay grad-yellow">
        <div class="card__title">Auctions</div>
        <div class="card__description">
          Description goes here.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__image" style="background-image:url('http://www.megaauctions.net/images/btn-auctions.gif')"></div>
      
      <div class="card__content">
      </div>    
    </a>
  
    <a href="#" class="card grad-babyblue">
      <div class="card__overlay grad-babyblue">
        <div class="card__title">Buying</div>
        <div class="card__description">
          Description goes here.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__image" style="background-image:url('http://www.megaauctions.net/images/btn-buying.gif')"></div>
      
      <div class="card__content">
      </div>    
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="card grad-salmon">
      <div class="card__overlay grad-salmon">
        <div class="card__title">Selling</div>
        <div class="card__description">
          Description goes here.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__image" style="background-image:url('http://www.megaauctions.net/images/btn-selling.gif')"></div>
      
      <div class="card__content">
      </div>    
    </a>

  
  </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS...

```
.container{
    background-image:url(http://www.megaauctions.net/images/bkg-subs-deep.gif)
}
.cards{
    display:grid;
    gap:1rem;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:1rem;
}

@media (min-width:59em){
.cards{
    grid-template-columns:repeat(2,1fr)
}
}

.card{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(2,1fr);
    grid-template-rows:300px 1fr auto;
    color:#fff;
}

@media (min-width:31.25em){
.card{
    grid-template-columns:160px (2,1fr);
    grid-template-rows:1fr auto
}
}

@media (min-width:50em){
.card{
    grid-template-columns:300px (2,1fr)
}
}

@media (min-width:59em){
.card{
    grid-template-columns:160px(2,1fr)
}
}
.card__overlay{
    min-height:300px;
    display:none
}

@media (min-width:59em){
.card__overlay{
    position:relative;
    opacity:0;
    display:grid;
    justify-items:center;
    align-items:center;
    grid-column:1/4;
    grid-row:1/3;
    transition:opacity .3s ease-in-out}
}

.card:hover .card__overlay{
    min-height:300px;
    opacity:1
}

.card__content span{
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    padding:1rem 3rem;
    color:#fff;
}

.card__image{
    grid-column:1/3;
    grid-row:1/2;
    min-height:157px;
    background:no-repeat 
    }

@media (min-width:31.25em){
.card__image{
    grid-column:1/4;
    grid-row:1/3
}
}

.card__content{
    grid-column:1/3;
    grid-row:2/3;
    padding:1.5rem}
    
@media (min-width:31.25em){
.card__content{
    grid-column:2/4;
    grid-row:1/2}
}


 .grad-yellow {
    background-color:#f3d250;
    background-image:linear-gradient(140deg,#f3d250,#EEA315);
}
.grad-babyblue {
    background-color:#90CCF4;
    background-image:linear-gradient(140deg,#90CCF4,#578FEE);
}
.grad-salmon {
    background-color:#F78888;
    background-image:linear-gradient(140deg,#F78888,#E7298C);
}
```

code in fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mattcomps/2eLzkwts/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answers your query

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8tkeyx0b/2/)

what i have done is giving relative style to the parent buttonhomea .
then on hover showing the hidden div.

```
.card__overlay{
  position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
opactity:0;
z-index:-1;
}
.buttonhomea{
  position:relative;
}
.buttonhomea:hover .card__overlay{
  opacity:1;
  z-index:1;
}
```

and added html

```
  <div class="card__overlay grad-yellow">
        <div class="card__title">Auctions</div>
        <div class="card__description">
          Description goes here.
        </div>
      </div>
```

under each buttonhomea class